# How to make subscribe landing page for blog?

Tags: blogger

I have a blog on blogger and I want to create a landing page whereby I ask the user for their email address. I don't want an RSS feed. I simply want a way for them to give me their email address so that I can personally email them about updates to my blog.

Comment: Do you mean a landing page as in everyone who visits your blog sees that page before they see your blog? I feel like that will probably not make visitors very happy, and will likely drive them away from your blog.

Comment: No, there will be a link that will take the user to a blank page with just a field asking for their email address. I'm looking for something really simple. A single text field that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Forms might be a good solution for you.  With Google Forms, you can create a custom form which stores the results in a Google Spreadsheet private to you.  Google Forms will generate the HTML which you can put on your blogger page.

http://www.mayvelous.com/2009/02/19/adding-contact-form-on-blogger-or-blogspot-blogs-with-google-form/